# Changing maps by mouse click (onclick event) with D3.js

Tags: d3.js, maps

I need to change one map to another by clicking on it. I wrote some code, but it doesn't work.

Part of the code for map drawing and changing:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.scale(550)
.translate([mapWidth / 2, mapHeight / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
.projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

queue()
.defer(d3.json, mapFile0)
.defer(d3.json, mapFile1)
.await(ready);


function ready(error, map0, map1) {

 var myMap = svg.selectAll("path")
 .data(topojson.feature(map0, map0.objects.countries).features)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("d", path)
 .attr("class", "state")
 .style("fill", "#cccccc")
 .style("stroke", "#ffffff")
 .on("click", changemap(map1));

  changemap(map) {
  myMap.data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.countries).features)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("d", path)
 .exit().remove();
 }

});
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four obvious problems stand out...

1. myMap shouldn't be an enter() selection.  You should save the update selection instead, not the enter() selection to later call data(), enter(), append(), like this:

   ```
   var myMap = svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(topojson.feature(map0, map0.objects.countries).features);

   myMap.enter().append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .attr("class", "state")
       ...
   ```
2. The changemap function is never declared because you're missing the function keyword.
3. In changemap, you cannot exit() from your enter() selection.  Again, you need to take care to save the update selection so you can enter/exit/etc without chaining:

   ```
   function changemap(map) {
       myMap = myMap.data(topojson.feature(map, map.objects.countries).features);
       myMap.enter().append("path");
       myMap.attr("d", path);
       myMap.exit().remove();
   }
   ```
4. You shouldn't call changemap(map1) as a parameter to on().  You should provide an event handler that on() can call when the event happens:

   ```
   .on("click", function() {
       changemap(map1);
   });
   ```

You may have other problems with this code but you should fix these problems before you proceed...

Comment: There is `TypeError: myMap.data is not a function` in `changemap(map)` function, some problem with the scope.

Comment: you can just do myMap = svg.selectAll('path').data... again instead

Comment: Thx, `.selectAll` makes deal, but can you explain why previous version didn't work?

Comment: I can't see your code, so I'm not sure, but if you did: ```var myMap = svg.selectAll('path').data(...);``` myMap will have a data function.  If you later do ```myMap = myMap.data(...);``` myMap will have a data function.  Not sure where you went wrong but if you post your code I can try to figure it out...

Comment: My bad, `changemap(map)` was defined not inside `ready(map0, map1)` function. Thanks, for help!